# Storing the Uploaded image?

Tags: python, postgresql, pyramid, wtforms

I am using a basic **WTForms**  **FileField** so far i am able to upload the file but its not getting stored in directories but its getting stored in **POSTGRESQL** database as `<Binary data>`. How to store it in directories and display in the browser.
I am not sure if i am doing it right. I just want to upload images and display them in browser, thats it.

**Article Model**

```
class Article(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'articles'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    body = Column(Text, default=u'')
    image_field = Column(BYTEA)
    category_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Category.id))
    category = relationship(Category)
    created = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    edited = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)

    @classmethod
    def all(cls):
        return DBSession.query(Article).order_by(sa.desc(Article.created))

    @classmethod
    def by_id(cls, id):
        return DBSession.query(Article).filter(Article.id == id).first()

    @property
    def slug(self):
        return urlify(self.title)

    @property
    def created_in_words(self):
        return time_ago_in_words(self.created)

    @classmethod
    def get_paginator(cls, request, page=1):
        page_url = PageURL_WebOb(request)
        return Page(Article.all(), page, url=page_url, items_per_page=4)
```

**View.py**

```
@view_config(route_name='article_action', match_param="action=create",
             renderer="edit_blog.mako",
             permission='create')
def article_create(request):
    article = Article()
    form = ArticleCreateForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        if form.image.data:
            filename = request.POST['image'].filename
            input_file = request.POST['image'].file
            file_path = os.path.join('static/images', filename)
            with open(file_path, 'wb') as output_file:
                shutil.copyfileobj(input_file, output_file)

        form.populate_obj(entry)
        DBSession.add(entry)
        return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('home'))
    return {'form': form, 'action': request.matchdict.get('action')}
```

File gets stored in database but not storing in images directory.

Answer (score 1):

`file` is a python file-like object with the data. I guess you should read from it and write what you read to `output_file`.

```
    with input_file as infile, open(file_path, 'wb') as output_file:
        infile.seek(0)
        shutil.copyfileobj(infile, output_file)
```

Comment: thats what `shutil.copyfileobj` does, better than your code :/